# xidel: is it possible to declare a variable for a XPath expression?

Tags: shell, xpath, xidel

Like

```
xmlstarlet sel --var xp 'xpathExpression' -t -v '$xp' file.xml
```

is it possible to use *internal variables* in `xidel`?

I know I can use `shell` and "double quotes", but that's not the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[readme](https://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel_readme.txt), or `xidel --usage`:

> ```
> Variable assignment:                                         $var := value
>
>   adds $var to a set of global variables, which can be created and accessed everywhere.
>   (Xidel prints the value of all variables to stdout, unless you use the --extract-exclude option)
> ```

So, for instance:

```
$ xidel -se 'var:="bar"' -e '"foo"||$var'
var := bar
foobar

$ xidel -s --extract-exclude=var -e 'var:="bar"' -e '"foo"||$var'
foobar
```

Or of course with the XQuery [Let Clause](https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-31/#id-xquery-let-clause) (not global):

```
$ xidel -se 'let $var:="bar" return "foo"||$var'
foobar
```

---

`xidel --help`:

> ```
> --variable=<string>    Declares a variable (value taken from environment if not
>                        given explicitely) (multiple variables are preliminary)
> ```

So, for instance:

```
$ xidel -s --variable="var=bar" -e '"foo"||$var'
$ xidel -s --variable var=bar -e '"foo"||$var'
foobar
```

Comment: Thanks, but what means `||` ? I know XPath separators `,` and `|`. Maybe a `OR`?

Comment: In a real use case: `xidel -se 'xp:=//div[@data-click-id="background"]/div[@data-adclicklocation="title"]/div/a[@data-click-id="body"]' -e '$xp/@href|$xp/div/h3/text()' "https://www.reddit.com/r/bash"` but I have annoying newlines

Comment: It not works as `xidel -e '//div[@data-click-id="background"]/div[@data-adclicklocation="title"]/div/a[@data-click-id="body"]/@href|//div[@data-click-id="background"]/div[@data-adclicklocation="title"]/div/a[@data-click-id="body"]/div/h3/text()' "https://www.reddit.com/r/bash"`

Comment: `||` --> [3.6 String Concatenation Expressions](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#id-string-concat-expr).

Comment: I'm not what sure what you're trying to do, but I'd say this is beyond the scope of this question. So, please start a new question.

Comment: This might help `var=bar xidel --variable=var -se '"foo"||$var'`

Comment: @potong That's how you can use _external_ environmental variables, while Gilles asked for _internal_ variables. I've added a `--variable` example nonetheless.